# What is the different between using the doOnEach, onError, onComplete within subscribe versus calling such functions on a Flux?

Tags: spring, project-reactor

I'm trying to figure out if there's a difference between the two, but can't really tell if throwing them in subscribe is just syntactic sugar or not.

I've looked at the docs but am having a hard time differentiating between the two use cases

e.g.

```
someflux.doOnEach(somefunction).doOnError(somehandling)
```

versus

```
someflux.subscribe(somefunction, somehandling)
```

EDIT: fixed incorrect method names

Comment: Note that the methods on `Flux` are `doOnEach` and `doOnError` (not `onEach` and `onError`)  (I can't edit it because the change is less than 6 chars)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are very closely related.

However, there are at least two use cases where you *must* use the `.doOn*` methods (rather than the arguments to `.subscribe`):

1. If you want to add side effects somewhere *not* and the end of the operator chain  (rather than only at the end), OR
2. If you do not control the subscription

More specifically:

### #1 Side effect behavior placement within a chain

The `.doOn*` methods can be placed *anywhere* within an operator chain.  On the other hand, the arguments to `.subscribe` are effectively always at the *end* of the operator chain.

For example, consider the following contrived example:

```java
Flux.range(0, 5)
        .doOnNext(i -> System.out.println("A: " + i))
        .filter(i -> i % 2 == 0)
        .doOnNext(i -> System.out.println("B: " + i))
        .subscribe(i -> System.out.println("C: " + i));
```

`A` will see values `0-4`, but `B` and `C` will only see `0`, `2`, and `4`.

Note that B and C are effectively the same, since both operate on signals at end of the operator chain.

### #2 When you do not control the subscription

There are a lot of cases where you do not call `.subscribe` yourself.  Instead, you just return the `Mono`/`Flux` from your method, and allow something higher in the stack to subscribe.  (For example: WebFlux controllers)

In this case, since you're not calling `.subscribe`, you have to use the side effect operators, rather than arguments to `.subscribe`.